# Slow SSR loading time on firefox - Mui, TSS-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I am trying to migrate my CSR website to an SSR one with **[Mui v5](https://mui.com/) and [Tss-React](https://docs.tss-react.dev/)** to use the JSS Syntax for style. It was successful until i see that on **Firefox** the loading time is near **15 seconds** to initially load the homepage and a little less for the heaviest subPages.

I tried other browsers such as Chrome or Edge and it worked fine with **20x less time** to fully load a page.

Im' not using any framework such as next, or razzle for SSR just Node with express and react so i don't know where this could come from because it's really weird that it's working on other browsers than Firefox, I also have a 700 lines `style.js` with my principal JSS object, can it come from here?

### App.js

```js
import { makeStyles } from "tss-react/mui";
import styles from './styles'
[...]
const useStyles = makeStyles()(styles)

export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
        <div className={classes.responsiveMainContainer} >
          <TopMenu />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />

            <Route path='/vous-etes' element={<VousEtes />}>
              <Route path=':type/:supplyChoice' element={<VousEtes />} />
            </Route>

            <Route path='/nos-solutions' element={<Solutions />}>
              <Route path=':type' element={<Solutions />} />
            </Route>

            <Route path='/publications/:article?' element={<Publications />} />
            <Route path='/publications' element={<Publications />} />

          </Routes>
        </div>
       <Footer/>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
}
```

clients.js and server.js created according to **[mui - SSR guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/)** and **[TSS - SSR](https://docs.tss-react.dev/ssr/other-backends)** for the tss part

### client.js

```
[...]
import theme from './styles/theme';
import createMuiCache from './createMuiCache';

const cache = createMuiCache();

function Main() {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot( document.querySelector('#root'), <Main />);
```

### server.js

```
[...]

import renderFullPageExampleMui from './renderFullPageExampleMui.js'
import createMuiCache from './createMuiCache';
import { getTssDefaultEmotionCache } from "tss-react";
import theme from './styles/theme';

function handleRenderTSS(req, res) {
  const cache = createMuiCache();

  const emotionServers = [
    cache,
    getTssDefaultEmotionCache({ "doReset": true })
  ].map(createEmotionServer);

  const context = { };

  const html = renderToString(
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <StaticRouter context={ context } location={ req.url }>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>,
  );

  const styleTagsAsStr = emotionServers.map(
    ({ extractCriticalToChunks, constructStyleTagsFromChunks }) =>
    constructStyleTagsFromChunks(extractCriticalToChunks(html))
  ).join("");
    
  res.send(
    renderFullPageExampleMui(html, styleTagsAsStr)
  );
}

const app = express();

function returnStatic(req, res){
  res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname+ req.path)
  );
}

app
.use('/', express.static('public'))
.get('/*.(js|bmp|webp|png|jpg|svg|ico|gif)',returnStatic)
.use('/build', express.static('build'));

app.use(handleRenderTSS);

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am the author of TSS react. Sorry I didn't update the instructions for setting up SSR in "other framworks" in a long time.  
Would you open an issue about it on the tss-react repo?  
If you provide me with a testable repo it helps a lot.

Comment: I just updated the documentation. Let me know if after updating to the latest version of tss and mui your problems persist: https://docs.tss-react.dev/ssr/other-backends

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. So I used both cache for mui and tss-react and the loading time seems the same.

Comment: So it works much better when i set both cache to the key:css and the prepend value to true for the tss cache like this:
`function createTssCache() { return createCache( { key: 'css', prepend: true} ) }`
`function createMUICache() { return createCache( { key: 'css'} ) }`
I don't know if it's a normal behaviour or not

Comment: Thank you for the update. No it's not a normal behaviour. Feel free to open an issue about it!